# android JSONException index 1 out of range [0..1] (Parse 2 json arrays inside 1 loop)

Tags: java, android, json, org.json

I have code like this, the value of `jArrAnswer` is

```
[{"answer":"Yes"},{"answer":"No"},{"answer":"maybe"},{"answer":"yrg"}]
```

the result from `jArrAnswer.length()` is 4

but why I got error

> org.json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1).

```
 try {
        JSONArray jArrAnswerid = new JSONArray(answerid);
        JSONArray jArrAnswer = new JSONArray(answer);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArrAnswer.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObjAnswerid = jArrAnswerid.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject jObjAnswer = jArrAnswer.getJSONObject(i);
            String ansid = jObjAnswerid.getString("answerid");
            String ans= jObjAnswer.getString("answer");
            GroupModel item2 = new GroupModel(String.valueOf(i + 1), ans, ansid);
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("asdf", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: can you please post your Json Response?

Comment: What is `jArrAnswerid.length()`??

Comment: Check my edit post

Comment: your {"answer":"Yes"} answer is object not array

Comment: jArrAnswerid.length() is ID

Comment: please add your full json response...

Comment: in the other cases this is true @RatilalChopda

Comment: please add jArrAnswerid  response

Comment: The stack trace tells you the line number where the exception happens. So you know which array does not have an index 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are iterating the `for loop` over `jArrAnswer` while your fetching the index `i` over `jArrAnswerid`.

Check and make sure that the `jArrAnswerid.size()` is **equal** to the  `jArrAnswer.size()`.

Print the `jArrAnswerid.size()` and check.

Comment: thanks dude, the value of jArrAsnwerid.length is different from jArrAnswer.length

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
try {
        JSONArray jArrAnswer = new JSONArray(answer);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArrAnswer.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObjAnswer = jArrAnswer.getJSONObject(i);
            String ansid = jObjAnswer.getString("answerid");
            String ans= jObjAnswer.getString("answer");
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("asdf", e.toString());
     }
```

provided "answer" is your json array response

Comment: I've been thinking about this from the beginning, but my needs are different. So I made 2 json arrays

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String json = "[{\"answer\":\"Yes\",\"answerid\":\"1\"},{\"answer\":\"No\",\"answerid\":\"2\"},{\"answer\":\"maybe\",\"answerid\":\"3\"},{\"answer\":\"yrg\",\"answerid\":\"4\"}]";

try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    if(jsonArray != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String answerId = jsonObject.getString("answerid");
            String answer = jsonObject.getString("answer");
            //Use answerId and answer
        }
    }
} catch(JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```