# Volley JSON PARSING Error json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, object

I am unable to Fetch JSONARRAY. Currently, I am making a Request that is sending me back a response that includes Arrays and objects . This has the Array inside an Array and I am unable to fetch Data form it as its gives the error if index 1 out of range[0...1]

```
`{
"ItemDetails": [
    {
        "LocationName": "JLT A Cluster",
        "Products": [
            {
                "Barcode": "5760466743686",
                "MainGroupName": "Chilled",
                "OnHandQty": 0,
                "Price": 10.5,
                "ProductName": "Mozzarella Portions",
                "SubGroupName": "Cheese Fats Butter"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"Status": {
    "Error": "",
    "ResultCode": "1",
    "ResultStatus": "Success"
}
}`
```

And Here is my Code

```
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        Log.d("APPPPPPPPPPPPP", response.toString());
                        try {
                            JSONObject status = response.getJSONObject("Status");
                            int Resultcode = status.getInt("ResultCode");
                            Log.d("",""+status.getString("ResultCode").toString());

                            if(Resultcode == 1){
                                JSONArray ItemDetail = response.getJSONArray("ItemDetails");
                                String LocationName = ItemDetail.getJSONObject(0).getString("LocationName");
                                   JSONArray Products = ItemDetail.getJSONArray(1);
                             //   JSONObject info = Products.getJSONObject(0);
                                   Log.d("HEYYYYY",""+Products);

                                //String ame = ItemDetail.getJSONArray(1).getJSONObject(0).getString("Barcode");



                            }else if(Resultcode == 109){

                            }



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        //tv.setText(response.toString());

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("EROOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOR", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
```

I am able to fetch atleaset Location and can easily fetch all the data from Status but cant fetch from inside of a products.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android JSONException index 1 out of range \[0..1\] (Parse 2 json arrays inside 1 loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418094/android-jsonexception-index-1-out-of-range-0-1-parse-2-json-arrays-inside-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
 JSONArray Products = ItemDetail.getJSONArray(1);
```

try to add this

```
JSONArray Products = ItemDetail.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("Products");
```

Comment: I am confused because it should be on 1 rather then on 0 position

Comment: your product array is inside the object, and that object is part of ItemDetails array

Comment: thats how you are going to retrieve it

Comment: String Name = String.valueOf(Products.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("Barcode"));
Gives this Error

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value 5760466743686 at Barcode of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: String Name = String.valueOf(Products.getJSONObject(0).getString("Barcode"));

Comment: try this : String Name = String.valueOf(Products.getJSONObject(0).getString("Barcode"));

Comment: Ohh Got it I was mistakenly using JsonArray in the End .

Comment: Thanks For your Guidance. Proper Result showing now.

Comment: I will recommend you to learn more about json and how to parse json, thanks